# How to load a large file into Adonis JS divided into chunks?

Tags: javascript, blob, nodes, chunks, adonis.js

I'm doing the server side of the site on the Adonis JS framework.
I have been tasked with loading large files, to solve this problem I decided to use file loading by chunks.
I have found some client-side code and it seems to work.

Here is the code on client side: https://codepen.io/chaly7500/pen/YzQyZNR

The code on the server side:

```
//routes.ts.

apiGroup('v1', 'files', Route.group(async () => {
  Route.post('upload', 'Files/UploadController.index')
}))
```

```
//UploadController.ts.
'use strict'
import {HttpContextContract} from "@ioc:Adonis/Core/HttpContext";
import MediaRepositories from "App/Repositories/MediaRepositories";

export default class UploadController {
   public async index({request}:HttpContextContract){

     const file = request.file('file')
     // console.log(file)
     return await MediaRepositories.createMedia(file)
   }
}
```

```
//MediaRepositories.ts

'use strict'
Import Application from "@ioc:Adonis/Core/Application";


export default class MediaRepositories {


  static async createMedia(file) {
    await file.move(Application.publicPath('media/transientmodels'))
  }

  static async updateMediaById(){

  }

  static async updateMediaByIds(){

  }
}
```

After uploading to the server, I have a blob file
And when I change the blob file to blob.png the image breaks

Has anyone implemented uploading large files using AdonisJS?

Or how to correctly convert blob file to image or video?

**Main question:**
How to upload big files to adonis and not get request timeout error ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to solve the loading problem with this library
https://www.npmjs.com/package/file-chunked

```
//UploadController.ts
'use strict'
import {HttpContextContract} from "@ioc:Adonis/Core/HttpContext";
import parseJson from "parse-json";
import MediaRepositories from "App/Repositories/MediaRepositories";
export default class UploadController {
  public async index({request}:HttpContextContract){
    
    const file = await request.file('file')
    const chunkMetaDataStr = await request.input('chunkMetadata');
    const chunkMetaData = await parseJson(chunkMetaDataStr);
    return await MediaRepositories.createMedia(file, chunkMetaData)

  }
}
```

```
// MediaRepositories.ts
'use strict'
import Application from "@ioc:Adonis/Core/Application";
import FileChunked from "file-chunked";
import * as fs from "fs";
import Media from "App/Models/Media";
import Env from '@ioc:Adonis/Core/Env'

export default class MediaRepositories {


  static async createMedia(file, chunkMetaData) {

    await file?.move(Application.publicPath('media/transientmodels/' + chunkMetaData.FileGuid + '/tmp_chunks'));

    await FileChunked.upload({
      chunkStorage: Application.publicPath('media/transientmodels/' + chunkMetaData.FileGuid), // where the uploaded file(chunked file in this case) are saved
      uploadId: chunkMetaData.FileGuid,
      chunkIndex: chunkMetaData.Index,
      totalChunksCount: chunkMetaData.TotalCount,
      filePath: file?.filePath,
    });

    if (chunkMetaData.Index == (chunkMetaData.TotalCount - 1)) {
     
        fs.copyFileSync(Application.publicPath('media/transientmodels/' + chunkMetaData.FileGuid + '/tmp_chunks/' + file.clientName),
          Application.publicPath('media/transientmodels/' + chunkMetaData.FileGuid + '/tmp_chunks/' + chunkMetaData.FileName));

 
    }

    
  }
}
```